# How Can I display the Employee number In the Employeename column .Incase the Employee name is NUll

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table

```
Emp
(
    Empno   NUMBER(4),
    Ename   VARCAHAR2(10)
);
```

It has a lot of Records. I want to display all employee names except if the employee name is null. In that case, we display the employee number.

Output Like:

```
select ename from emp;

Ename
------------
ravi
chadu
null------here we have to display the Empno
ramana
moulali
null------here we have to display the Empno.
```

What query accomplishes this using the case and Decode Concepts?

Comment: Use `nvl(Ename, Empno)`

Answer (score 2):

You appear to want something like

```
CASE WHEN ename IS NULL
     THEN to_char(empno)
     ELSE ename
 END
```

Comment: @Justin- one thing I'd like to ask- there's a bit of debate on using CASE expressions or NVL function. Which one would be faster and why?

Comment: @Rachcha - I'd use `coalesce` in real code.  This appears to be a homework assignment where the purpose is to learn how to use `case` and `decode`.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov- Good catch.  I missed the `to_char` call.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NVL(ename, empno)` instead. Read more about NVL [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm).